# Laravel - Uploading multiple images for a single request doesn't work well on shared host

Tags: php, laravel, server, image-uploading, shared-hosting

I am uploading more than 12 images files for a single requests but the online server refuses to upload those images. In my local machine it works fine, i can upload more than 20 images at once. I have configured the PHP settings for max_file_uploads = 60, upload_max_filesize=100M, post_max_size = 125M in php.ini, both on my local machine server and online server. While sending the page loads unfinishing, and at the end after a long time it responds with a Network Protocol Error, which says that:

"An error occurred during a connection to www.mydomain.com. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the network protocol was detected."

See the screen shots of other different error responses i've also got after many trials, and it still takes a long time of loading to get those responses after sending.

[image: a busy cat]

[image: a busy cat]

The images that i am uploading are being saved on server but not all. When i upload 20 images for a single request, it can get only 8 or 10 and sometimes the last image is cut short(interrupted) before it is fully uploaded, see its picture below.

[image: a busy cat]

I need to get all the images i am uploading like in my local machine, and with a quick response. What else i can do for configuration in PHP or elsewhere? What's wrong on shared hosting server? Please, if you have any answer to this, you can tell me what i can do, to get all uploaded images files with a quick response.

Comment: The error message you're getting is pretty clear - your host has a limit of 6 minutes (360 seconds) for the request to complete. It's presumably taking longer than that for your images to upload. This could be your connection, their connection, or just really big files. They're unlikely to be willing to lift the limit, so consider uploading files individually (perhaps via AJAX) or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz, what do you mean uploading files individually via AJAX, Can you give me an example or a link to find out how it is done for multiple images?

Answer (score -1):

It's clearly because of a timeout error. It's not acceptable to send multiple files with one request. Even if you get it to work right now, it will fail from time to time depending on the user connection speed and file size. Also you mentioned a quick response. So you definitely need to use ajax upload to upload files simultaneously. There are multiple upload libraries such as [dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com).

Comment: I am using Ajax to upload, and i am converting each image to base64 before uploading to the server. My code does what an Ajax library can do for me, that's why i did not use it. Tahnks! If this problem is not solved easily, i am going to try dropzone and see if it can help

Comment: It's entirely acceptable to send multiple files with one request. OP would probably have no trouble if they were uploading, say, 500 tiny 1x1 images. OP would have the same issue with a *single* file if it were large enough and on a slow enough connection to take more than 360 seconds to upload.

Comment: Yup for 500 tiny images maybe. But he is talking about a real world usecase when user is trying to upload multiple images e.g. profile image. And you see he is getting a timeout after 6 minutes. So for sure tiny images is not the case here.

Comment: What? 3 times more? I didn't know this. I am converting to base64 because i need also to change the positions of images using jQuery UI to sort them, and i'll need to edit those uploaded images later

Comment: @Hervera It's not 3x the size. base64 adds a 33% overhead. Arash is mistaken there. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding. "The ratio of output bytes to input bytes is 4:3 (33% overhead)."

Comment: @ArashTabrizian I'm objecting to the blanket statement that "It's not acceptable to send multiple files with one request". That's simply untrue.

Comment: @ceejayoz OK! :))) "It's not acceptable to send multiple LARGE files with one request". So is the statement correct now?

Comment: Still not correct. With the right server config, you could *easily* send multiple large files. In this case, it's not the number of files that fundamentally matters; it's whether the HTTP request can complete in under 360 seconds. *Zero* uploads and a `sleep(361)` in the PHP would cause the same problem.

Comment: @ceejayoz Man! You are a CTO! Why are you insisting on something that is not a best practice?!! I did not say it's "impossible", I said it's not acceptable! It's not a good approach. When you have a file upload, and he/she is allowed to upload multiple files, It's always better to handle file uploads in parallel. Because it reduces the upload time and also it reduces the chances of uploading a corrupt file.

Comment: It's unlikely to reduce upload time, as upstream bandwidth is usually the limitation. I'm not aware of anything that indicates doing them in parallel reduces chances of a corrupt file. You've made a number of false or unsupported statements here that I've doubts about, and thus I say so here.

Comment: @ceejayoz 
1.On same bandwidth, parallel processing will always reduce the time! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science))
2. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6

Comment: If you have 100 MB worth of photos to upload, and you can upload 10 MB per minute, it's going to take 10 minutes to upload the photos, regardless of whether you do them one by one or all in parallel. C'mon, dude.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm actually wasting my time here because you are playing with words! You now have an exception for the word "always" that I used! So I should have gone for the word "unlikely" that you used. In a real world scenario - including many types of user connections with different Qos and different browser types that put different restrictions on upload size and different amount of file that needs to be uploaded - I can assure you that it's most likely to reduce time! p.s my final comment here.